# Global "Module" in C# similar to VB.NET's Module

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've been searching around here and elsewhere for an answer to this, but I haven't found an exact answer.

I'm fairly new to C#.  In VB.NET, you can define a Module, like a class, which has some limitations and also some benefits.  One of its great benefits is that you can access all of its members globally if you've imported the namespace (i.e. "using" in c#).  For example:

```
Private Sub Test()
    MsgBox(Now)
End Sub
```

In the method above, MsgBox is a method in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction module and Now is a property in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime module.  I don't have to qualify the call to either of them in order to use them, although I could:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Now)
End Sub
```

I use this feature all the time in my own projects by building my own modules with utility methods and properties.  It's very, very useful.  Is there an equivalent in C#?

Comment: Not really, everything has to be attached to *some* sort of type.

Comment: Create an abstract class with static methods.

Comment: You can create static classes or use the Singleton design pattern but you still need to import the namespace.

Comment: No, but you could create a method and a property in a base class and derive from that if you really want it.  However, that's rather ilmiting, since you can only derive from one class.  You can also just call a static method or static property directly.

Comment: @Asad -- Yes I understand I can do that.  I would then have to qualify every call with the appropriate class name, which I'd have to remember.  If I have multiple such classes, say in a very large project or solution referencing multiple assemblies with many of these, it becomes increasingly inconvenient to remember the names of the static classes.  When all I have to do is know that I can type "Get" and up pops 20 different methods whose names start with "Get", then ... well, you can see how that is much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A module in VB.NET is the exact equivalent of a *static class* in C#.  The only difference is that the VB.NET compiler by default puts your declarations inside the Module in the global namespace.  This is a practice that the C# team does not favor, for a good reason, you have to use the class name when you reference a member of the static class in the rest of your code.  In other words, you have to use Math.Pi, not just Pi.

It doesn't have to be this way, you can put a Module in a Namespace:

```
Namespace Contoso.Foobar
    Module MyModule
        '' etc..
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Now it is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, except for why they don't favor that practice.  If you expound that, I will accept your answer.

Comment: There isn't much to expound, adding identifiers to the global namespace is something that made sense 20 years ago when programs were still teeny.  VB.NET *had* to support it for backwards compatibility with old code, C# didn't have that burden.

Comment: @roryap its a frequently requested feature. Its neither a great feature nor a terrible feature. Features like that rarely get budget allocated to them, so, no feature.

Comment: Sounds like a good feature for some `using` syntax.  I'd probably never use it though, I like the current design..

Comment: Very useful feedback, all.  @Hans -- I'm still curious as to why it doesn't make sense in programs written today which aren't teeny.  I work on a lot of large projects where it's a quite a convenience.

Comment: Also, @Eric -- it's a honor.  Thanks for weighing in.

Comment: @roryap. You're welcome. To clarity the feature I meant was alluded to by mike Christensen. Allow a using directive to specify a static class. This would in my opinion have been nice for extension methods also.